# Wordpress - Different sidebar for each page

Tags: wordpress

Client needs an website to migrate into WordPress.

In this website each page has an sidebar with different content inside it

In some page accordion comes under sidebar, in some just text and images are visible

How to implement this in WordPress?

If template has to be created, there are many page it cant be done so

Even for every page different sidebar  widget is not also possible

Guide me a way to implement this

Comment: Please try with this plugin..... http://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-sidebars It will work.

Comment: I built a plugin for doing just this. It allows you to create as many sidebars as you want and then select them when publishing a page / post https://github.com/p0lari3/wordpress-sidebar-select

Answer (score 5):

A different sidebar (widget) are can be added to each page in two steps:

1. Add the sidebar to the theme template using the page slug as part of the sidebar name. This ensures that the sidebar has a unique name for that page.
2. Register the sidebars for each page in `functions.php` for your theme

### Add the sidebar to the theme template

In your theme template, add the following code where you want the widget area to be:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    dynamic_sidebar( 'widget_area_for_page_'.$post->post_name );
?>
```

### Register the sidebars

In `functions.php` for your theme add the following block of code to register the sidebars for each page in your site. Note that it includes draft pages etc so that you can edit the widgets while still in draft mode.

```
function myTheme_registerWidgetAreas() {
    // Grab all pages except trashed
    $pages = new WP_Query(Array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit'),
        'posts_per_page'=>-1
    ));
    // Step through each page
    while ( $pages->have_posts() ) {
        $pages->the_post();
        // Ignore pages with no slug
        if ($pages->post->post_name == '') continue;
        // Register the sidebar for the page. Note that the id has
        // to match the name given in the theme template
        register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          => $pages->post->post_name,
            'id'            => 'widget_area_for_page_'.$pages->post->post_name,
            'before_widget' => '',
            'after_widget'  => '',
            'before_title'  => '',
            'after_title'   => '',
        ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myTheme_registerWidgetAreas' );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: how do we add the sidebar that is created in the widget to the page options in order to select a different sidebar for each page? without the use of plugins.

Answer (score 2):

There's a great plugin for this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-sidebars/

> Sometimes it is necessary to show different elements on the sidebars
>   for some posts or pages. The themes nowadays give you some areas to
>   put the widgets, but those areas are common for all the posts that are
>   using the same template. NOTE: You need to use a theme that accepts
>   widgets to make this plugin work.

[image: Screenshot]

I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much.. will chk it

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/ plugin. Once activated you can choose what [widgets](http://jetpack.me/support/widget-visibility/) display on what pages:

> The Widget Visibility module enables you to configure widgets to appear only on certain pages (or be hidden on certain pages) by using the Visibility panel.

[image]

> Visibility is controlled by five aspects: page type, category, tag, date, and author. For example, if you wanted the Archives widget to only appear on category archives and error pages, choose “Show” from the first dropdown and then add two rules: “Page is 404 Error Page” and “Category is All Category Pages.”

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just tried custom-sidebars with the latest version of wp.  Had a hard time deleting it.  Database is still messy.  Plugin did not work.  Maybe the 'pro' version is useful, but the 'non-pro' version would not add a sidebar to the page.  It was clunky and did not allow per-page sidebars.  It says its not been tested with the latest wp, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: This type of response should have been a comment, not an "Answer".

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom sidebar for for each post and pages with the help of plugin. There are a few plugins which enables you to create your custom sidebar. Here in this tutorial we are using Easy Custom Sidebars. Download and install this plugin in your website and activate it.

After successfully activating the plugin go to **Appearance > Sidebar Replacement**

From this page give a name to your custom sidebar and click on the **Create Sidebar** button. After that go to the **Sidebar Properties** option. Here you need to select the properties where you want to replace your created custom sidebar instead of theme sidebar. You can view your available option in the drop-down menu. Select it and provide a description on the **Sidebar Description** field.
Now in the last step select the post or pages to add this custom sidebar. You can see all the option in the left column.  You can select specific post, page, category , tag, author to add this sidebar. Just select it and click **Add to sidebar** option.

For better understanding you can [follow](https://niamrox.com/how-to-create-custom-sidebar-for-each-post-and-page-in-wordpress/) this tutorial